# Which answer to accept if the answer with solution is based on an answer with the important insight?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, accepting, guidelines, answers

Let's say that someone only gives a hint and someone else, perhaps even the asker, then creates a full solution based on it. Which of the answers should be the accepted one?

On the one hand, it should be the full solution because it is the solution and should be marked as such, on the other hand, the original insight deserves credit.

What do you think?

Check my question for a specific example: [Listings: different counters for different listing environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3993/listings-different-counters-for-different-listing-environments)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Giving credit is done by upvoting. An answer has to be selected as accepted because it is the most complete answer, not the first with the nice insight. My 2 cents.

Comment: Ah, ok, I thought some credit is given for accepted answers too. Perhaps I should tag this question also as for beginners :)

Comment: @fraktalek : indeed, there is 15 reputation given for the accepted answer. But that reputation is meant to reward the best/most complete answer. I'm not so much into that reputation thing, but -as Willie Wong also mentions- about the usefulness of the site for future users. Hence...

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Joris: one of the mechanisms built in to SE software is that an accepted answer will appear at the top of the list when one opens the webpage. So for the sake of people who searched on Google or on this website and found the question, the "best" answer (as in most complete, or most applicable to the actual question asked, or with the most detailed example) should be the one accepted.

Comment: Or, my criterion, the answer such a reader is best off first reading.